# Display tab as read only

Tags: visualforce, tab

I need to display a Tab which shows the list of all the records of my Custom Object (Custom_Object__c) without the "New" button. I don't want the user to create any record from the tab as the records of this object are being created from trigger.
I tried removing the "New button" from Search layout of object which is hiding the "New" button once I click on "All" records on tab. But when I click on Tab for the first time, it does show me "New" button.

I also tried to achieve this with VF page which is displaying the list of records but it is also displaying 2 buttons for "New Custom_Object" and "Change Owner". Please suggest how can I remove these buttons. Below is my VF page.

```
<apex:page standardController="Custom_Object__c">   
<apex:enhancedList type="Custom_Object__c" height="700" rowsPerPage="50" id="AllRecords" customizable="false"></apex:enhancedList>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first you create your visualforce page then go to object detail page and check search layout there are
sobject List View , then edit this list view there are standard button which you want to display . unmark button which you don't want to display then save. [image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its working. I already unchecked that option earlier but didn't checked my VF page after that.

Comment: great good day :)